# Pegar Value de vários botões no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, value

Como pegar o valor de varios button utilizando JavaScript ?

```
Qual cor você prefere ?
_______ ______ ______
|verde| |Azul| |Rosa|
------- ------ ------

Qual sorvete você prefere ?
___________ _________ ______
|Chocolate| |Morango| |Uva|
----------- --------- ------
```

E se a pessoa selecionar "Azul" e "Chocolate" por exemplo esse valor seja exibido em uma div.

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso, seria melhor vc utilizar [input type="radio"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp) no seu HTML e pegar o valor desses inputs com JavaScript para inserir dps em uma div.

Comment: e que eu estou tentando fazer a mesma logica dos botões do buzzfeed por exemplo, que são botões pelo que entendi, mas não sei se estou certa se isso é possível

Comment: Então você poderia colocar funções na propriedade "onclick" dos botões onde ao clicar em um deles vc coloca a propriedade "disabled" dos outros dois como "true"

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Verde</option>
  <option>Azul</option>
  <option>Rosa</option>
</select>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nesse caso ele sai do padrão que eu estou tentando fazer, no caso eu queria algo parecido com a logica dos botões do buzzfeed